# Cannot edit column type or delete it in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, column, excel, import

I have imported an excel file into SharePoint 2013. One of the columns I imported was `PolicyType`. It is currently set as a text field but I need to change it to a choice from a menu field. I don't have this option and I noticed I also cannot delete this column either. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Delete that column and create the new column of same name. Put the choices that are required. And don't forget to delete the "PolicyType" column from recycle bin.

Comment: OP mentioned that he is unable to delete this column. And it is true that for some column, there is no delete option. I found this issue while deploying custom list definition from visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Try following PowerShell script to delete it forcefully and be aware of after effect!

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity http://YourSiteUrl
$list = $web.Lists["Your List Name"]
$column = $list.Fields["Name of Column"]
$column.Hidden = $false
$column.ReadOnlyField = $false
$column.Allowdeletion = $true
$column.Sealed = $false
$column.Delete()
$list.Update()
```

For some column, there is no delete option. Specially when you deploy custom list definition using visual studio. In that case, PowerShell has solved my issue. So try to delete you column using PowerShel and create new.