# Specific column cannot be edited, every other one can

Tags: column, edit

After exporting an excel table to a SharePoint List, I would like to edit one of my columns to change the type from Single line of text to Choice. However, one specific column does not have the "Edit" option under Column Settings while every other column does. I have "No" checked for content approval requirement. What could be different about the specific column in question and how can I go about getting the option to edit it?

Comment: May be sealed property is true for this column. Refer this link ....https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160051/cannot-edit-column-type-or-delete-it-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: @RohitWaghela link provided suggests I delete column and replace with new. Column has 500+ values I would need to copy over, if one can advise on how to do this while keeping the same values from old column let me know.